# Should I use @Api or @ApiModel in Spring Boot code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm facing an issue where some part of the codebase is using @Api on some controller and other part is using @ApiModel annotation from swagger/springfox.

I am not sure which one I should be using for my controllers.

My research on the subject lead me to conclude that I should use @ApiModel. Because @Api has some deprecated properties (see [javadoc @Api](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/Api.html) and [javadoc @ApiModel](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModel.html)), for example `description`.

What is the big picture that I am missing in my understanding ?

As a note, my dependencies contains `swagger-annotations`, `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use OpenApi 3. When you use this you dont need this annotations because you declare your documentation in a single yml file. And you also dont need 2 dependencies just 1 will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand how can I use OpenApi 3 but thank you ! As a note, I am not the owner of the dependencies, and therefore I can't change them.